# System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 0100000c

Tags: xamarin.forms

Hi I am new to Xamarin Forms. I am building my Solution and got Succeeded.
However, when  I try to run the solution I am getting the exception

```
"System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 0100000c".
```

I tried "Clean Solution", "Rebuild Solution" and Restart Visual Studio.

The problem remains.